# In SQL Server, can I vary what "entity.table" means in a SQL expression by connecting to a different database?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, database-schema

I am working on a PHP 7.2 application that is running in a Windows + SQL Server environment. I have been asked to make a number of changes on an ongoing basis.

After working on this project for a few months, it is becoming increasingly frustrating that there are no automated tests. Furthermore, to work properly it needs to connect to enterprise visualisation software that I do not have, so it is fairly much a system that has to be tested in production.

To ameliorate these risks I have Dockerised it, so at least some of it will run on my laptop. I have it running alongside a copy of SQL Server, also in a container. I am now planning to retrofit some API tests, and I have spied some SQL code that may be a problem.

As per my usual practice, I would like to be able to run two databases locally, one called "local" that for ad-hoc testing and general development, and another called "testing", for automated tests. The testing one would be torn down and rebuilt for every test run. However, all the queries look a bit like this:

```
SELECT [Username], [User_ID], [Forename], [Surname],
       [Title], [Job_Title], [Email],[Permissions],
       [Password_Created], [Enabled], [Change_Password]
FROM [MASTER].[User]
WHERE CONCAT(
    [Username],' ',[Forename],' ',[Surname],' ',
    [Email],' ',[Job_Title]
) LIKE :searchTerm
```

So, all the tables are expressed as `[MASTER].[Table_Name]`. I assume that `[MASTER]` is a schema name, though I am not familiar with SQL Server. There are quite a lot of these queries. I have set up my initial tests so that the temporary database appears in the form `[MASTER_TESTING].[Table_Name]`, and so I need all the queries to change to the other schema for the tests.

One approach to solve this is to inject a schema name into each application class that references `MASTER`, so I can configure it (either for run-time or testing). However, given that I have no tests, changing a lot of code in this way feels risky, and I was wondering if there is an alternative.

Can I set up a database name in the PDO connection string, or issue a `USE` command, to get `[MASTER].[Table_Name]` to refer to any number of databases, or do I just need to modify each query?

Comment: Is there a reason your replicated testing database has to change the schema to MASTER?  If you just keep the same schema it would reduce the risk and be a whole lot easier.

Comment: @BrianPressler: it's on `MASTER` already, and I have got some tests to pass by creating a database in `MASTER_TESTING`, so on my present trajectory, I would have to change it. However, I don't want to, and your answer (and David's below) give me hope that I can leave all queries on their current schema. I am not entirely _au fait_ with schemas, but I will investigate further. Thanks!

Comment: There is no table "user" in schema master. How did this table come here? Who created it and why? Creating tables in the master schema is bright madness and should normally not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tables are expressed as [MASTER].[Table_Name]. I assume that [MASTER] is a schema name,

Correct.  `MASTER` here is a name of a schema in the session's current database.  This is a 2-part name, and is resolved relative to the session's current database.

> can I set up a database name in the PDO connection string, or issue a USE command, to get [MASTER].[Table_Name] to refer to any number of databases

Yes.  Reconnecting to another database or issuing `USE database_name` will change the sessions current database, and 2-part names will be resolved relative to the new database.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had worried I had a hardwired code mess on my hands (the code isn't great, so it would not have been a grand surprise). I will try adding a `USE` device to the app's connection code, or perhaps changing the `Database=` parameter in the connection string.

Comment: I've added the code that seemed to be required to get my current/default user to use a `MASTER` schema with a new database.

Answer (score -1):

Following David's helpful advice, I thought I would show what I am doing to connect to the `MASTER` schema in a blank test database.

The following is the code I am using to tear down and create my database. I am connecting the test/client side, and the API/server side, to the standard `sa` user for SQL Server in Docker.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $dbname;
CREATE DATABASE $dbname;
CREATE SCHEMA [MASTER] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[MASTER] TO [dbo];
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, ALTER, EXECUTE, CONTROL ON SCHEMA::MASTER TO dbo;
USE $dbname;

/* Create my application tables here for test */
```

I was unable to create tables in `MASTER` code until the `GRANT` was issued. I don't know if this could be done more succinctly, but it is only for a throwaway database, and test code does not have to be perfect.

Comment: Creating tables in the MASTER schema is **bright madness**. Please stop tampering around with the master schema and follow the standardized paths of using SQL server.

Comment: The master schema is something like the core engine of SQL server. Tampering around here is like opening the engine of your car. I don't understand what you want to do and why you think it's necessary to touch the master schema.

Comment: ah okay I see. do you have possibilities to change the structure of the database? Normally, you either put your tables into the "dbo" schema (which is default), or even better, you create schemas of your own, and put all your data there.

Comment: BTW: If you would ever move your database to other customers, or move it to azure, then the master schema is normally blocked by the admins. So it would be really good if you could create your own schemas and move your tables there,

Comment: I have the possibility of doing whatever I like, as long as I work for free. In general, when working for a client remotely, I estimate the scale of a piece of work in hours, and then wait for it to get authorised. I've worked a lot of _pro bono_ hours on this already, and I'm not looking to do more. I doubt that a charged piece of work would be possible here, and I would have to admit to the client that it would introduce risk for the sake of architectural and theoretical purity. I doubt they would go for it.